# MacBook Pro - Only runs while MagSafe charger connected

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

My 2013 MacBook Pro only runs while the MagSafe power charger is connected.

Model Number: A1425 (EMC 2672)

1. When the charger is disconnected system immediately powers off (no
   shutdown).
2. MagSafe LED is always amber.

Is this a common problem? What is the most likely cause?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds very much like the battery has died.

What does the battery meter say in the menu bar, if you click it? Usually if the battery has already breathed its last, it will say "service battery" or even "replace battery immediately".

Comment: Worth mentioning: if the laptop is still under warranty (or if you have AppleCare), then you should be able to get it replaced by Apple free of charge.

Comment: Unfortunately I purchased it second hand a few months ago. It's an early 2013 model so I assume it's out of warranty.

Comment: I believe you can check by going to the 'about this Mac' menu, selecting more information and going to the warranty section. Even so, laptop batteries do die, so an out-of-warranty repair should not be TOO expensive. Tell them your sob story and they might even help! Apple has been known to be generous with their repairs.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a issue with U7000 ISL6259 this IC is in charge of battery management.  Check it also the surrounding resistors and caps.

Comment: Why does all the battery stuff have to be on the opposite side of the board? :( Can't reach without completely removing the logic board from its case